# How do I make my flexbox work with my layout, my sidebar is still stuck at the bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sidebar

After much experimenting and hairpulling I have yet to find a way to make flexbox work, so that my sidebar is next to my main-content. Not only that but for some reason after adding flexbox, my second "main post" suddenly turns transparent on small screensizes. I have no idea what is going on there...

I am beggin on my knees here - Please, someone cast a glance at my code and tell me what on earth I am doing wrong, these flexboxes are mocking me.

I placed the site on both jsfiddle, codepen and included it here for your viewing pleasure, The CSS is mobile first with an addition for larger screens at the bottom, and it is this part I need help with - the sidebar drops below the content on mobile, so I dont mind it not being next to the maincontent there:
https://jsfiddle.net/Gingerx/9a7xhxqg/

https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/aELgXJ?editors=1100

```
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">

  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="maincontent">

 <article class="topcontent">

<header>
<h1>Velkommen til vores hjemmeside</h1>
</header>

<footer>
   <p class="post-info">  hjem for herreløse hunde </p>
</footer>
                <img class="mellemh" src="http://i1246.photobucket.com/albums/gg611/Rcoslive/tumblr_opglesDkzP1rfn5l1o1_540_zpsk1t1dhzo.jpg" alt="Kdog"/>

<!-- 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <div class=brødtekst>
          <p> Vi har stadig brug for din hjælp for at kunne sikre Kattelaugets eksistent, og modtager donationer, store som små. Donationer kan trækkes fra i skat, og er med til at sikre at vi kan give vores killinger og katte mad, varme og et sted at være, indtil de bliver adopteret.
          </p></div><!-- End, brødtekst -->
       </article>

   <article class="bottomcontent">
        <!-- 2 -->
        <header>
          <h1>Lidt om os</h1>
        </header>
        <footer>
          <p class="post-info"> Sådan drives kattehjemmet</p>
        </footer>
        <!-- INDSÆT TEKST HER 2 --------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <div class=brødtekst>
<p>Alt dette kan naturligvis ikke lade sig gøre uden lokalbefolkningens hjælp. Nu sidder du helt sikkert og klapper i hænderne over hvor fantastiks det er at vi redder så mange katte, og overvejer hvordan DU kan hjælpe til med at støtte vores dejlige kattehjem, men bare rolig, det kan vi nemt svare på:</div><!-- End, brødtekst 2 -->
<ul>
<li><a href="adopt.html">Køb din kat hos os.</a></li>
<li><a href="donation.html">Tilbyd at tage en rengørings/fodervagt</a>, tider varierer fra en gang om ugen, til hver 14. dag.</li>
<li>Bliv medlem, det koster kun 200 kr. årligt.</li>
<li>Giv et bidrag til driften af kattehjemmet <a href="donation.html">her</a>. Alle beløb modtages med stor glæde</li>
</ul> </p>
      </article>
</div> <!-- End, maincontent-->

<div class="sidemenu">

  <aside class="top-sidebar">
<article>
  <h3> <a href="#">Plejefamilier og frivillige søges</a></h3>
</article>
 </aside>

<aside class="middle-sidebar">
 <article>
<h3>Ugens kat</h3> <img src="" alt="Kdog">
    <p><a href="#">Mathilde</a></p>
</article></aside>

<aside class="middle-sidebar">
  <article>
  <img src="billeder/ungkat/sailor.jpg" alt="Sailor" >
   <p> <a href="#">Sailor</a> </p>
</article>
</aside>

<aside class="bottom-sidebar">
    <article>
<h3>Ugens killng</h3>
    <img src="billeder/killinger/mr.grey.jpg" alt="Mr.Grey" >
     <p><a href="#">Mr.Grey</p></a>
     <p>en herlig lille gut med fuld fart på!</p>
    </article>
</aside>

</div> <!-- End, Sidemenu -->
</div> <!-- End, wrapper-->
</body>
```

And then the CSS
    /******************************************************************/

```
/*                            RESET                               */

/*                        ______________                          */

/*meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/               v2.0 | 20110126*/

/*License: none (public domain)                                   */

/******************************************************************/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/*           GEN                    */

/* Box-sizing = width or height + padding + border = reelle højde og bredde. */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/*         Billeder! Img!    ******      Video!            */

.mellemh {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 2px;;
  width: 10%;}

.sidemenu img { width: 40%; float: left; margin-right: 5px; }

/*          Tekst!          */

.sidemenu .b {font-weight: bold; color: orange;}
.content h1, h2, h3 {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  }

.sidebar h1, h2, h3 {margin: 0 0 2% 0;}

  h1 {font-size: 1.5em; color: orange;}
  h2 {font-size: 1.3em;color: orange;}
  h3 {font-size: 1.1em;color: orange;}

  .brødtekst 
  {white-space: pre-line;}


/*    SIDEBAR!                         */

.sidemenu { display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;}

.top-sidebar {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.middle-sidebar {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1% 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.bottom-sidebar {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
      padding: 0 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.sidemenu p {color: grey;}


/*     MAIN!   **** BODY!  */
.wrapper {display: flex;
flex-direction: column;}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
  text-align: left;
}

.body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Alt er centreret*/
  width: 99%;
  clear: both;
}

.maincontent {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */    }

.wrapper {display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;}



.topcontent {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
    padding: 3% 3% 3% 3%
}

bottomcontent {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
    padding: 3% 3% 3% 3%
}


/*  BIG SCREENS START HERE*******************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.5em) {

/* IMG!  ******   VIDEO! ***/

.sidemenu img { float: none; width: 70%; margin: 2 auto; }
.top-sidebar img {width: 70%;}

  .mellemh {
  padding: 10px 20px 0 2px;
  width: 35%;}


/* MAIN! BODY! *********************************************************/
  .wrapper {display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;}

.body { width: 90%;}

.maincontent {
   width: 71%;
   display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}

.topcontent {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */

  padding: 1% 3% 1%% 3%
}

.bottomcontent {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Fox*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  padding: 1% 5% 3% 3%
}


/* SIDEBAR!***************************************************************/

  .sidemenu { display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;}

.top-sidebar {
          text-align: center;
          width: 18%;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
          margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
            }

        .middle-sidebar {
          text-align: center;
              width: 18%;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
          margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
          border-radius: 5px;
          }

        .bottom-sidebar {
          text-align: center;
          width: 18%;
         background-color: white;
          padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
          margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
                }
```

Comment: Your flex container (`.wrapper`) is set to `flex-direction: column`. This stacks flex items vertically in a column. Remove it. `flex-direction: row` is the default.

Comment: If this was not the internet, I would bake you a batch of gratitude-cookies. Thank you so much Michael, you are a kind soul.

Answer (score 0):

This line of CSS is making your main content and sidebar display in a column instead of in a row:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

What you want is `flex-direction: row` which is the default for flexboxes, so all you need to do is remove one line.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```